# The specified value "undefined" is not a valid number

Tags: javascript, html, input, datatable, getelementbyid

I´m learning for an exam which is about company inventories.
I thought i could do myself a favor and learn something new about coding while learning for this exams.
Normally i only do frontend with very little javascript at my company.

What i´m trying to do is setting up a table with 2 input rows.

Row 1: Input from me
Row 2: Sums of my input

i put in a button that should give the value i enter at Row 1 to another field in Row 2.

When my input type is number im getting this:
The specified value "undefined" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

When my input type is text im getting:
undefined

I´m pretty sure something about my function is wrong but i can´t figure it out and when i search for my issue i only find more complex cases which i also 
don´t understand.

Thank´s in advance for any help :)

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var x = document.getElementById("1").value;
        document.getElementById("ro").value = x;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td><b><button onclick="test()">test</button></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="flex-table">
                    <table id="names">
                    <!--Names--><!--Names-->
                        <caption>A: Vermögen</caption>
                            <tr><th>I. Anlagevermögen</th></tr>
                            <tr><td class="first">Grundstücke</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="second">Gernotstraße</td> </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id="input">
                    <!--Input--><!--Input-->
                        <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
                            <tr><th><p>€</p></th></tr>
                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr><td><form id="1"><input type="number" value="0"></form></td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id="values">
                    <!--Values--><!--Values-->
                        <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
                            <tr><th><p>€</p></th></tr>
                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr><td><input id="ro" type="number"value="0" readonly></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your id must be assigned to a input element, not the form itself.

Comment: oh i see that was stupid, it works now.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake**

1. First thing `id` is not only numeric. so you must mix with some string
2. And `document.getElementById("string1")` is placed with `form` not a input.so add id to input instead of `form`

```html
<script>
  function test() {
    var x = document.getElementById("string1").value;
    document.getElementById("ro").value = x;
  }
</script>


<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b><button onclick="test()">test</button></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="flex-table">
          <table id="names">
            <!--Names-->
            <!--Names-->
            <caption>A: Vermögen</caption>
            <tr>
              <th>I. Anlagevermögen</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="first">Grundstücke</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="second">Gernotstraße</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table id="input">
            <!--Input-->
            <!--Input-->
            <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <p>€</p>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <form><input id="string1" type="number" value="0"></form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table id="values">
            <!--Values-->
            <!--Values-->
            <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <p>€</p>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="ro" type="number" value="0" readonly></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was a stupid mistake but can u explain me what u mean with the <id> part, i think it doesn't matter what u choose as id or does it?

Comment: yes does not a matter.You could set anything as a id.But its not good practise.In future more no of coding and variable.its will be more confusing and complex.Use some related name of the activity element,`eg:input get username set id="username"` . variable and name defining is one of the biggest task in coding

Comment: okay i see, better implement the good habits before getting used to bad ones.
Thank you prasanth :)

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the value of `form`, which has no value. You probably mean to read the value from the `input` element.

```js
function test() {
  var x = document.getElementById("1").value;
  document.getElementById("ro").value = x;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b><button onclick="test()">test</button></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="flex-table">
        <table id="names">
          <caption>A: Vermögen</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>I. Anlagevermögen</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="first">Grundstücke</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="second">Gernotstraße</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="input">
          <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <p>€</p>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id="1" type="number" value="0">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="values">
          <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <p>€</p>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="ro" type="number" value="0" readonly></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second table should be corrected in the following way. The id value "1" was referring the form element and not the input element.

```
<table id="input">
     <!--Input--><!--Input-->
     <caption>&nbsp;</caption>
     <tr><th><p>€</p></th></tr>
     <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr><td><form><input type="number" value="0" id="1"></form></td></tr>
</table>
```